# Docs for writing a new language binding for Selenium 2 / WebDriver

Tags: binding, selenium

I find the Selenium site a little hard to navigate.  Can someone point me to docs that will help me write language bindings for Selenium?  I'm hoping not to have to do a straight port of some other language's bindings, because I want to understand Selenium better and use my current languages paradigms.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you look at this already? http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/WritingNewDrivers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There really isn't any such documentation.  You're best off joining the #selenium IRC channel on Freenode, where the developers hang out, and asking questions.

Comment: This answers the question indirectly (not the answer I was hoping for but ...!).  Thanks.

Comment: Don't let it get you down, though.  There are quite a few helpful developers who've done exactly what you're contemplating, and there are at least 4 people or groups who've done it already, without visiting the channel first.  One guy wrote an Erlang (I think) client that way.

Comment: My bad - it's the Haskell client.  Equally non-mainstream, though :-)

Comment: Any update on the status these days? I am also looking for information for writing a binding for the Julia language.